# Generate IDs in headings

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

My site uses Jekyll with Redcarpet markdown parser. I'd like to make it so my headings are automatically generated with ids:

```
# My heading
```

Becomes:

```
<h1 id="my-heading">My heading</h1>
```

But I haven't found a way.

I'd like to stick with redcarpet as my markdown parser, but it's not essential. If there's another one that supports all the same features then I'd happily consider it. I especially like that redcarpet generates code blocks in pygments format.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about how you would do it, but maybe [creating a custom renderer is the way](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-you-can-even-cook-your-own). Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solutions is [@maul-esel's Github Issues answer](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1249#issuecomment-20228613):

The [redcarpet README](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/#darling-i-packed-you-a-couple-renderers-for-lunch) mentions the config option `with_toc_data`. This generates IDs for headings that look like `id="toc_0"` etc.

You can enable it by adding this into your `_config.yml` Jekyll config:

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
    extensions: [with_toc_data]
```

It's not ideal - I'd prefer more semantic IDs like `id="my-heading"` - but it's Good Enough and it's super easy - it means I don't need to set up and learn another markdown parser (or work out how to extend the redcarpet).

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, it does work with Kramdown

```
$ kramdown <<< '# My heading'
<h1 id="my-heading">My heading</h1>
```

Comment: I looked at kramdown. It's a potential solution, but I much prefer the way redcarpet generates code blocks.

Comment: Maybe I just don't know how. With redcarpet I enclose my code in `\`\`\` css \ ... \ \`\`\`` and it puts pygments `<span>`s around all the relevant bits of code for highlighting. If I do the equivalent `~~~ css \ ... \ ~~~` for kramdown, it just surrounds my code with `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` but no pygments markup.

Comment: Yeah I don't care about that. I'm not really a Ruby guy, and I prefer language-agnostic solutions. I just want to get this working with the least effort possible.